# Suggest me the right AWS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, web, worker

My Spring boot application has REST endpoints and has scheduled tasks. Which AWS service should I use?

I was considering beanstalk, but there I have to choose a web or worker environment. Similar selection is required in Heroku also.

My application can withstand crashes, if it can spin up automatically.

Can you suggest an appropriate AWS service?

Answer (score 0):

although I'm not sure what your scheduled tasks are, I'd have a look at AWS Lambda

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must use AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Why?

All Cloud providers follow the paradigms below.

IAAS: Basically providers give VMs. You manage operating system, load balancer etc.
Exp: AWS Elastic Computing, GCP Compute Engine ..

PAAS: Basically Providers operate your operations, just deploy your code. (Generally if app is down, it can spin up automatically.)
Exp: AWS Elastic Beanstalk, GCP App Engine ..

For better understanding types of cloud computing, [read this doc.](https://aws.amazon.com/types-of-cloud-computing/?nc1=h_ls)